# Auto-fill input form with PHP, MySQL and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I had a problem with my auto-fill input form, with PHP MySQL and jQuery of course. So I have the select option form and some 'disabled' textboxes. And I want when I select the one of the option, the textboxes is auto-fill with value from the database

So there is my whole code :

PHP (Database connection) - I put it above my `<html>` code

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'db_mydatabase';

    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db);

    $user = '';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_payment") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

HTML

```
<select name="student" class="input-data">
    <option value="">-- SELECT STUDENT --</option>
    <!-- Do loop data from database -->
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id_user ?>">
            <?php echo $row->name ?>
        </option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<br />
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="output-id" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="output-name" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Total Payment</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="output-total" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input-data").on("change", function(){
        <?php $id_user = "$(this).val()"; ?>

        <?php $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_payment WHERE id_user = '$id_user'") or die (mysql_error()); ?>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data)): ?>
            $(".output-id").val(<?php $row->id_user ?>);
            $(".output-name").val(<?php $row->name ?>);
            $(".output-total").val(<?php $row->total ?>);
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    });
});
```

But when i try to select the option, the values are wouldn't appear. Can someone help me?

Comment: What if you remove this extra `<` in the 4th line of the jQuery part?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? This should be causing issues `while (row - mysql_fetch_object($query)):`..

Comment: Thanks @PhiterFernandes , removed already

Comment: @chris85 It is no error that reported but when I open my firebug, the java script code its just
`$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".input-data").on("change", function(){});
});`

Comment: Are you looking at PHP error logs?

Comment: @chris85 No, I don't know how to see it. But when my PHP script is going error, they will appear in Javascript code because i had put my `mysql_error()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about creating new page name process.php contain:

```
require_once "connectDB.php";

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST['one'])){
$json = array();
$id =  trim($_POST['one']);
$query = "SELECT id, name, total FROM tb_payment WHERE id_user = ?";
$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('s', $id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($nId, $nName, $nTotal);
while ($statement->fetch()){
   $user=array('id'=>$nId,'name'=>$nName,'total'=>$nTotal);
    array_push($json,$user);
}
echo json_encode($json, true);

 }
```

And the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input-data").on("change", function(){
            var id = $(".input-data").val();
            var data = 'one=' + id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //for each user in the json response
                            $(".output-id").val(data[i].id);
                $(".output-name").val(data[i].name);
                $(".output-total").val(data[i].total);
                        } // for

                    } // if
                } // success
            }); // ajax
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print

```
 $(".output-id").val(<?php print $row->id_user ?>);
 $(".output-name").val(<?php print $row->name ?>);
 $(".output-total").val(<?php print $row->total ?>);
```